# Configuring to detect if a command does not exist, suggest installation

Tags: zsh

Can the `zsh` shell be configured to show what `bash` shows when a command does not exist, similarly to this:

```
kahless:~$ sysv-rc-conf  
The program 'sysv-rc-conf' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:  
sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

rather than the ZSH prompt:

```
[kahless /home/teward]% sysv-rc-conf  
zsh: command not found: sysv-rc-conf
```

Note I do not want to change the prompt itself, but I want to change the result from `zsh: command not found` to a bash-like output of `The program 'progname' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:` or similar.

Is this possible with ZSH?

Comment: Please check https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593804/206574

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This feature is provided by the [`command-not-found`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/command-not-found) [image: Install command-not-found] package. Ubuntu installs it by default, and makes it active by default in bash but not in zsh. Just add this line to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
. /etc/zsh_command_not_found
```

Comment: This solution worked.  Is there a way to get rid of a line in the output, then? (note that it was included in the output, as was the `The program 'progname' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:` part)  `zsh: command not found: sysv-rc-conf`

Comment: @EvilPhoenix: Anywhere would do (except inside a function or something obviously). I don't know about removing the `zsh: command not found` line.

Comment: Okay, i can probably ignore the "command not found part".  Because the suggest installation part is nice, and its nice to knokw that it came up because a command didnt exist ;)

Comment: to turn of the `command not found` message you can add `exit` at the end of the function `command_not_found_handler` in `/etc/zsh_command_not_found`.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you might want to add a check if the file exists if you are sharing your .zshrc across distributions that do not have a `/etc/zsh_command_not_found` file:

```
[[ -a "/etc/zsh_command_not_found" ]] && . /etc/zsh_command_not_found
```

Also, in case you're using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), there already is a plugin, `command-not-found`, that you can add to your `plugins` variable that does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using *oh-my-zsh*, you can just instead look for "plugins" inside your `.zshrc`.

Add the [`command-not-found` plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins#command-not-found) to the list of plugins to autoload (this plugin is already installed by default).

Like this:

```sh
# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git command-not-found)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is through the command_not_found_handle() function in bash. bash provides a hook which is basically a function that is invoked when a command is not found. Ubuntu's bash implementation traps it and does a package search, while Debian's bash does not (and same with zsh). You may want to check out zsh's manpage to see if that has a similar function.

Here is how you can get started, hoping zsh is similar.

```
mpandit@mpandit-ubuntu:~$ command_not_found_handle() {echo 'Handler: Command not found!';}
mpandit@mpandit-ubuntu:~$ ddaadada
'Handler: Command not found!
mpandit@mpandit-ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: This isn't a difference in Debian and Ubuntu's bash. The difference is that Ubuntu installs `command-not-found` by default and Debian doesn't. The feature already exists for zsh as well, it's just not activated by default.

Comment: This assumes that command_not_found is not included in the system.  However it is not what I'm looking for.  Having said that, the answer from @Gilles is more along the lines of what i'm looking for, i'm just trying to figure out where to include the line he specified.

Comment: It's called `command_not_found_handler` in zsh.  See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you don't want zsh to have this behavior 100% of the time you can just manually do something like:

`/usr/lib/command-not-found urxvt`

or add command-not-found to your $PATH

Comment: when i asked this, i wanted it to work all the time :P